# Error 3021 when deleting item from recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I use the code below, I sometimes receive a Error 3021. This only happens when I have one record in the recordset. Can you please tell me why, and how to fix it? It seems I've tried everything!

Thanks

```
Private Sub cmdDelSelectedAction_Click()

response = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation required")
If response = vbNo Then Exit Sub

If Me.[Arrangement-Actions subform].Form.Recordset.EOF Then
    Me.[Arrangement-Actions subform].Form.Recordset.MovePrevious
End If

If Me.[Arrangement-Actions subform].Form.Recordset.BOF Then
    Me.[Arrangement-Actions subform].Form.Recordset.MoveNext
End If

Me.[Arrangement-Actions subform].Form.Recordset.Delete
Me.[Arrangement-Actions subform].Form.Recordset.MoveNext

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have one record and you delete it, how should the MoveNext call work?

Comment: What row is highlighted when you receive the error?

Comment: LarsTech - I may have made a mistake here then. I was getting the error before I added the .MoveNext call. PowerUser - it errors on the RecordSet.Delete line

Comment: Could someone please let me know how I should rewrite my code to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but I think the code would look like this:

```
Private Sub cmdDelSelectedAction_Click()
  Dim rec As Recordset = Me.[Arrangement-Actions subform].Form.Recordset
  If Not rec.BOF Or Not rec.EOF Then
    If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
      rec.Delete
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

I find it a little odd that in your code you would ask to confirm to delete the record, and then before deleting the record, you would perform a MoveNext or a MovePrevious on the recordset.  I would stay away from doing that since the end user might be deleting a different record than they were expecting.